# How to install Geany Third-Party Plugins

Tags: plugins, geany

I really like the Geany IDE and use a couple of the Geany plugins, but I have no idea where to start in order to install third-party plugins. I've checked  the [Geany Manual - plugins section](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#plugins) but I didn't find it much help.

The specific plugin is for emmet and can be found [here](https://github.com/sagarchalise/geany-emmet).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could contact [sagarchalise](https://askubuntu.com/users/1543/sagarchalise) on this question.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a perfect answer but there is a similar plugin called "zencoding" (github.com/codebrainz/geany-zencoding) which has a much clearer readme. To get this package to work (after following the readme) it is important to change the default keybinding (keyboard shortcut) as CTRL+SHIFT+E is used for the function "find usage" as welll as the zen coding function "expand abbreviation".

Answer (score 1):

The references you mention are clear:

- User installation:  `/home/<username>/.config/geany/plugins/`
- System wide installation: `/usr/lib/geany/`

Comment: I really appreciate the response but you have just listed two file directories. I am self-taught so there are gaps in my knowledge apologies. I have (sort of) solved my problem as I have, instead, installed zencoding (https://github.com/codebrainz/geany-zencoding) which has a much clearer readme.

Thanks!

Comment: @moroncodes yeah it is fine. that plugin has installation script, so no need for manual setup. However, I would recommend reading little about *freedesktop* folder structure and *Makefile* environment variables to to get enough background to read such doc.